# Bluetooth chat on android platform

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have tried the sample code of Bluetooth chat from Android SDK.
The code has no errors, Installed the APK on device, while opening the Bluetooth chat, Force close is thrown.

Kindly help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Thanks for your reply.
Below are the logcat logs. Am using the API level 8 and 10. 
Thanks in advance

```
`at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)' 
'at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)'
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)'
'at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)' 
'at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)'
'at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)'
'at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)'
'at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
'at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)'  
'at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)'
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  
 com.mca.distance.Bluetooth_Chat.BluetoothChat in loader                          
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.mca.distance.Bluetooth_Chat-1.apk]
```

Comment: Kindly take logs of force close and post them here... :)

Comment: Kindly help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried i on your phone or only on the emulator?

It may be that your emulator does not have bluetooth capability and therefore crashes. Give that a shot and let us know